# Angularjs Entity Framework

Tags: javascript

I have two models :

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<NumberModel> Numbers { get; set; }
    }


 public class NumberModel
    {
        public long NumberId { get; set; }
        public string Num { get; set; }
        public long UserId { get; set; }

        public UserModel User { get; set; }
    }
```

Relationship between tables is one to many, how i can display data using Entity Framework and Angularjs using foreign keys , something like : |NAME| NUMBER|.

This is code only for one table :

```
CONTROLER:
 public IHttpActionResult GetUsers()
        {




            using (ContactEntities oContext = new ContactEntities())
            {


                var query = from a in oContext.User select a;



                IList<UserModel> list = query.Select(x => new UserModel
                {
                   Name=x.Name,
                   UserId=x.UserId
                   Numbers?????


                }).ToList();


            }   

                };
                return Ok(list);
            }   

        }


<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>Todo</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Todo</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>{{item.UserId}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.NumberId}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Num}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


var Proba = angular.module("Proba", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', { controller: ListCtrl, templateUrl: 'list.html' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });


Proba.factory('Todo' ,function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/user/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });

});


var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location, Todo,Num) {
    $scope.items = Todo.query();

};
```

Comment: And you question is...?

Comment: Are you looking to join Users table to Numbers table and select from both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IList<UserModel> list = query.Select(x => new UserModel
{
    Name=x.Name,
    UserId=x.UserId
    Numbers=x.Numbers.Count()
}).ToList();
```